# Why does my video playlist on click not change to the video I selected . Via Javascript , Django, Python

Tags: javascript, python, django

The Playlist is supposed to let me click a video on the right and make it the main video, so you can watch it. The video scroller letting us know what time we are on the video also won't let me pick where I want the video to start. So if someone wanted to rewind you cannot. I think both these issues have to that i am using static files with django. I tried used the regular   with t
he src but i get no video at all. I am using Django, Javascript. HTML5 , CSS & Visual Studio Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
<div class = "container5">
    <div class="main-video-container">
        <video  {% load static %} src ="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 1-4.mp4" %}" loop controls class="main-video"></video>
        <h3 class="main-vid-title"> Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 1-4</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="video-list-container" > <!-- This is where we keep adding videos to our list-->
        <div class="list active">
            <video {% load static %} src="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 1-4.mp4" %}"     class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 5-7</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <video {% load static %} src="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 5-7.mp4" %}" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 5-7</h3>
        </div><div class="list">
            <video  {% load static %} src="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 5-7.mp4" %}" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 5-7</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <video {% load static %} src="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 5-7.mp4" %}" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 5-7</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <video {% load static %} src="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 5-7.mp4" %}" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 5-7</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <video {% load static %} src="{% static "Chapter 3.1 Exercise 5-7.mp4" %}" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">Properties of Parallel Lines Exercise 5-7</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
     }
    .container5{
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin:100px auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-start;
        gap: 20px;
    }
    .container5 .main-video-container{
        flex: 1 1 700px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(246, 5, 5, 0.557);
        background-color: rgb(255, 119, 0);
        padding:15px
    }
    .container5 .main-video-container .main-video{
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width:100%;
    }
    .container5 .main-video-container .main-vid-title{
        font-size: 20px;
        color: brown;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container{
        flex:1 1 350px;
        height: 485px;
        overflow-y:scroll ;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(246, 5, 5, 0.557);
        background-color: rgb(255, 119, 0);
        padding:15px
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
      width: 10px;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
      background-color: #c71111;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap:15px;
      padding:10px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 15px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #eee;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list:last-child{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list.active{
        background-color: #d70f0f;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list.active .list-title{
        color: #1d4736;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list .list-video{
        width:100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .container5 .video-list-container .list .list-title{
        font-size: 17px ;
        color: #444;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Javascript is here

```
let videoList = document.querySelectorAll('.video-list-container.list');
videoList.forEach(vid =>{
    vid.onclick = () =>{
        let src = vid.querySelector('.list-video').src;
        let title = vid.querySelector('.list-title').innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('.main-video-container .main-video').src = src;
        document.querySelector('.main-video-container .main-video').play();
        document.querySelector('.main-video-container .main-vid-title').innerHTML = title;
    };
});
```

Comment: Why do you use the java tag for a JavaScript question?

Comment: @aled updated to javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Might I suggest expanding your question by adding what it says in the browser console. Theres a good chance your answer is in there. I might also suggest looking in the generated html, and testing the generated URLs manually to see if indeed the file is where its claimed to be.